# Formatting Year, Month, Day, and Hour into datetime object in Pandas Jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am have a TMY dataset with unique columns for year, month, day, and hour. I have created a datetime object with the year, month and day; however, I need to add the hour to the object so I can properly sort the dataset.

I started here:

[image]

Coded this:

```
# convert year, month, day integers to datetime objects
df_datetime = pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']])

# drop the original datetime components plus the 'SiteId' columns
df_mod = df.drop(['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'SiteId'], axis=1)

# concat two dataframes
df = pd.concat([df_datetime, df_mod], axis=1)
```

Got Here...
[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the column hour means the integer hour in 24h system, then the line below should do the trick:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour']], format = '%Y/%M/%D %H')
```

Comment: thank you @Crocs. This is very helpful and has solved my question.